# Haskell Syntax Error with nested ifs

Tags: haskell, syntax

I'm trying to do my homework but I get a syntax error that I don't understand.

```
data CTree a b =
        CNode (CTree a b) b (CTree a b) | -- left, value, right
        CLeaf a                           -- value
    deriving (Show, Ord)

-- a)
--

instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (CTree a b) where

    --
    -- Compares two CNode objects
    --
    (CNode left1 v1 right1) `compare` (CNode left2 v2 right2) =

        -- If the value of the first node is greater than
        -- the value of the second node, the result is GT.
        if (v1 > v2) then GT

        -- If the value of the first node is smaller than
        -- the value of the second node, the result is LT
        else if (v2 < v1) then LT

        -- We must compare the child nodes if the values of
        -- boths nodes equal.
        else if (v1 == v2) then

            if (left1 == left2) then
                (right1 `compare` right2)
            else
                (left1 `compare` left2)

main = do
    print "foo"
```

The error is (at the line of `main = do`)

> parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

I am aware that there are some overloads of the compare function missing, but the Syntax Error should not originate from that fact.

Comment: It seems like you just want to compare according to lexicographical ordering. You can do that by using the compare instance for tuples: `compare (CNode left1 v1 right1) (CNode left2 v2 right2) = compare (v1, left1, right1) (v2, left2, right2)`

Comment: If you still want to write it out explicitly (rather than using @user2407038's trick): Since you are comparing `v1` and `v2` all three ways it would probably be clearer (and more efficient) to use ``case v1 `compare` v2 of ...`` instead of nested `if`s.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, `if (v1 == v2)` has a `then` branch but lacks an `else` one. You should remove that `if`, which serves no purpose since you checked for `v1 < v2` and `v1 > v2` before.

Answer (score 1):

You should indent:

```
if (left1 == left2) then
    (right1 `compare` right2)
else
    (left1 `compare` left2)
```

one more layer, and provide an `else` for the corresponding `if (v1 == v2) then`.

Then you should remove `Ord` from the `deriving` and add an `Eq` instead. And since your `b` type is an `Ord` you can just rewrite your program as:

```
data CTree a b =
        CNode (CTree a b) b (CTree a b) |
        CLeaf a
    deriving (Show, Eq)

instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (CTree a b) where
    (CNode _ v1 _) `compare` (CNode _ v2 _) = v1 `compare` v2

main = do
    print "foo"
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3070167f70db935)

It is to notice that I've changed the meaning of the [`compare`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3acompare) function for `CTree` as you described it, because your function would never return [`EQ`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t%3aOrdering), which is actually an expected value.

But if you want to keep that behavior you can just do:

```
instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (CTree a b) where
    (CNode left1 v1 right1) `compare` (CNode left2 v2 right2) =
        if (v1 == v2) then
            if (left1 == left2) then
                (right1 `compare` right2)
            else
                (left1 `compare` left2)
        else v1 `compare` v2
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d3a3e572fc1c990)